# Invoking a method from PCL in Background service in separate thread Xamarin

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a method `PostToWebAPI` defined in my PCL. I have called this method in my background service implemented in my Android project as follows: My scenario is as follows:

```
[return: GeneratedEnum]
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {

    Toast.MakeText(this, "BackgroundService started..", ToastLength.Long).Show();

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoBackgroundJob(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

    base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return StartCommandResult.Sticky;

}


public async void DoBackgroundJob()
{
   // An instance of he class in my PCL to invoke the method PostToWebAPI
    WebServiceAPI webApi = new WebServiceAPI();
    await webApi.PostToWebAPI("Nissan", "2003");
}
```

My scenario is as follows:

1. The app does the same thing when it is launched manually. On launch, it sends data to the `PostToWebAPI`.
2. I have implemented a `Service` within the app, more specifically in the Android project that fires upon device boot. The `Service` as indicated above call the `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoBackgroundJob(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);`.
3. As it is an ongoing service, when I launch my app manually, it blocks the UI of my app.

My question is how can I avoid the blocking of the UI while the `Service` is running ? Even if the app is launched manually, it should post both the data from the app running and the `Service`. Please help.

Comment: An Android **`Service`** runs on the main/UI thread, so start a new thread (or use Task.Run to use a thread from the task threadpool) and do not block the return from `OnStartCommand`. FYI: There are other types of Android services that create a worker thread.

Comment: @SushiHangover : I have used `Task.Run` also. But same thing happens. And what do you mean by ` do not block the return from OnStartCommand` ?